# If I log into a PS3 with another account, will it forget the old user's password?

Tags: ps3, psn

I know somebody with a PS3 and I want to log into my old PSN account but I'm scared it'll log him out and he doesn't know his PSN password.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to your question, but a different solution.

If he doesn't remember his password he can still [recover it with his email address](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/account/forgotpw.html):

- Select `Forgot your password?` from the sign-in ID (e-mail address) and password screen.
- Enter your sign-in ID (e-mail address) and birth date.
- Reset your password using a PC.
  An e-mail message is delivered to the address that you used as your sign-in ID. Follow the steps in the e-mail message to reset your password using a PC.